# Beautiful soup module error(html parser)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html

I use beautifulsoup to find the number of pages on a webpage however when I write my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
import requests
import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
pages = soup.select('div.pagination a')

a = int(pages[-2].text)
print a
```

It gives the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/HangaarLab/Desktop/sonartik/sonartik.py", line 13, in
>   
>       soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>
> In another computer the code runs but it gives this warning: 
>   UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best
>   available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually
>   isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a
>   different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and
>   behave differently.The code that caused this warning is on line 14 of
>   the file C:/Users/Ar�elik/Desktop/sikayet/klo.py. To get rid of this
>   warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the
>   BeautifulSoup constructor.

I need the code to work in the computer that gives the first error. What should I do?

Comment: that does not look like bs4 syntax - it should be `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to import `BeautifulSoup` from bs4 package

```
import urllib2
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #here
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get("https://www.sikayetvar.com/onedio", headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
pages = soup.select('div.pagination a')

a = int(pages[-2].text)
print a
```

Answer (score 4):

Update

```
import BeautifulSoup
```

to

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

**Ex:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get("https://www.sikayetvar.com/onedio", headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")   #Use a parser to fix second error warning 
pages = soup.select('div.pagination a')

a = int(pages[-2].text)
print a
```

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is part of the bs4 package. To fix your code simply do:

```
pip install bs4
```

in the command line and change your import to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```